# Overwriting function in parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, class

I was just looking at this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-override-class-methods-in-Python#:%7E:text=In%20Python%20method%20overriding%20occurs,do%20not%20come%20in%20play.) where the code there is:

```
class Parent(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.value = 4
     def get_value(self):
         return self.value
 
class Child(Parent):
     def get_value(self):
         return self.value + 1
```

When the function `get_value` is run in the class Child, does it determine the value of `self.value` by checking what the value of `self.value` was in the function `init` in Class Parent, or by checking what the value of `self.value` was in the function `get_value` in class Parent?

**Update**

```
class Parent(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.value = 4
     def get_value(self):
         self.value = self.value + 7 
 
class Child(Parent):
     def get_value(self):
         return self.value + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

When you access the `self.value` in the `child` class it will get the current state of `self.value` that is in the `Parent` class. So if it is not changed it will return the one in `__init__` plus 1.

This example is a bit simplified, but if you will add a `setter` method to it, it will be better to understand what value it accesses.

Something like:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 4
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

class Child(Parent):
    def set_value(self, x):
        self.value = x
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value + 1

c = Child()
print(c.get_value()) # 5
c.set_value(3)
print(c.get_value()) # 4
```

Comment: I have just added extra code to the bottom of my original question. In my new example, will get_value in the child class return 12?

Comment: In my new code what is the flow, is it -

1) Run class Parent, function init
2) Run class Parent, function get_value
3) Run class Child, function get_value

Comment: When there is only `Child` instance there is no call for the `get_value` of the `Parent` class only the `Child` one. so it will be Run `Parent` init -> `get_value` in `Child`

Answer (score 2):

I'll simplify what Python does under the hood if you have the code from your update and then run:

```
child = Child()
print(child.get_value())
```

---

```
child = Child.__new__(Child) # first create the object
Child.__init__(child) # then initialize it
print(child.get_value())
```

---

```
# `Child` doesn't have a `__new__` property, it checks the `Parent` class, which doesn't have it either, so it checks `Parent`s parent class, which is `object`, which does know how to create an object!
child = object.__new__(Child)
# look up `__init__` on Child, it doesn't exist so check the `__init__` on the base class, Parent:
Parent.__init__(child) # then initialize it
# `child` doesn't have an attribute called `get_value`, look it up on its class, it finds it!
print(Child.get_value(child)) # prints 5
```

---

Note that at no point `Parent.get_value` is called. If you want subclasses to call methods on their superclass, you can use `super()`:

---

```
class Parent(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.value = 4
     def get_value(self):
         self.value = self.value + 7 
 
class Child(Parent):
     def get_value(self):
         super().get_value()
         return self.value + 1
```

If you use this code `c.get_value()` will return 12 if `isinstance(c, Child)`.